# How to use auto migration with loopback 4 for mysql datasource

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, loopback

Please , help
There is nothing about auto migration in loopback4 with a mysql datasource

Answer (score 1):

```
let auth = server.dataSources.auth;
auth.isActual( function(err, actual) {
    if (!actual) {
      auth.autoupdate(function(err, result) {
        console.log('Error in autoMigrate script',err);
        console.log("All tables are updated..");
      });
    }
  });
```

I hope this clarifies your query;
And auth is a datasource defined in datasource.json